# How can I make a multiselectpicklist disabled, based on checkbox?

Tags: apex, visualforce, checkbox

when All Employee checkbox ticked, the field cant be selected (disabled)
any solution?

[image: here]

**VisualForce Page**

```
<apex:page controller="preProcessController">
<apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock id="PreProcessPayroll" title="Pre Process Payroll" >
        <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" showHeader="false" >

             <apex:pageblocksectionItem >
                <apex:outputLabel value="Payroll Period" for="listPeriod"/>
                <apex:selectList id="listPeriod" size="1" multiselect="false" value="{!selectedPeriod}" style="width:150px"> 
                    <apex:selectOptions value="{!Period}"/> 
                    <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="listEmployee"/>
                </apex:selectList>   
            </apex:pageblocksectionItem>

            <apex:pageblocksectionItem >
                <apex:outputLabel value="All Employee" />
                <apex:inputCheckbox id="ProcessAll" label="Process All">
                </apex:inputCheckbox>
            </apex:pageblocksectionItem>

            <apex:panelGroup id="listEmployee">
                <c:MultiselectPicklist leftLabel="Available Employee" leftOptions="{!allEmployee}"
                                       rightLabel="Selected Employee" rightOptions="{!selectedEmployee}"
                                       size="14" width="475px"/>
            </apex:panelGroup>    

            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                <apex:commandButton id="RunPreProcess" value="Run Pre Process" action="{!RunPreprocess}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
```

**Controller**

```
public with sharing class preProcessController
{

    public SelectOption[] selectedEmployee {get; set;}
    public String selectedPeriod{get; set;}
    public String picklistVal;

    public PageReference selectedPeriod() {
        return null;
    }

    public PageReference SelectedEmpNo() {
        return null;
    }

    //========== get picklist value for Period Code ==========     
    public List<selectOption> getPeriod() {       
        List<selectOption> options = new List<selectOption>();
        options.add(new selectOption('', '- None -'));
        for (PYSETPAYPERIOD__c perCode : [SELECT Id, Name, Process_Flag__c FROM PYSETPAYPERIOD__c WHERE Process_Flag__c < 4 OR Process_Flag__c = NULL ORDER BY Name]) {         
            options.add(new selectOption(perCode.id, perCode.Name));       
        }
        return options;
    }

    //get all employee record
     public LIST<SelectOption> getallEmployee(){     
        LIST<HREMPINFO__c> empMember = [SELECT Id, Name, Full_Name__r.Name FROM HREMPINFO__c WHERE Id IN
                                        (SELECT Employee_No__c FROM PYEMPPAYPERIOD__c WHERE Period__r.Period__r.Id =: selectedPeriod)
                                        ORDER BY Name];

        LIST<HREMPASSIGNMENT__c> empAssignment = [SELECT Position_Name__c, Position_Name__r.Name, Employee_No__c  FROM HREMPASSIGNMENT__c];

        LIST<SelectOption> empList = new LIST<SelectOption>();

        for(HREMPINFO__c eM : empMember){
            for(HREMPASSIGNMENT__c eA : empAssignment){
                if(eA.Employee_No__c == eM.Id){
                    picklistVal = eM.Full_Name__r.Name + ' - ' + eM.Name + ' - ' +eA.Position_Name__r.Name;
                    empList.add(new SelectOption(eM.Id, picklistVal));}
                }
            }
            return empList;
        }

        public void RunPreprocess(){ 
        //query from empPayPeriod with limitation
        PYEMPPAYPERIOD__c[] empPayPeriod = [SELECT Period__r.Element_Name__r.Budget_Item_Code__c, Employee_No__r.Company_Name__r.Id, Period__r.Element_Name__r.Element_Group__c,
                                            Period__r.Element_Name__r.Id, Period__r.Element_Name__r.Element_Type__c, Period__r.Element_Name__r.Content_Value__c, Employee_No__r.Id,
                                            Period__r.Element_Name__r.End_Date__c, Period__r.Element_Name__r.Group_Display__c, Period__r.Element_Name__r.Group_Order__c,
                                            Period__r.Element_Name__r.Is_Value__c, Period__r.Period__r.Id, Period__r.Element_Name__r.Process_Sequence_ID__c,
                                            Period__r.Element_Name__r.Start_Date__c FROM PYEMPPAYPERIOD__c WHERE Period__r.Period__r.Id =: selectedPeriod];

        //create array of PYEMPELEMENT
        PYEMPELEMENT__c[] empElement = new PYEMPELEMENT__c[]{};

        //create single record of PYEMPELEMENT
        PYEMPELEMENT__c e = new PYEMPELEMENT__c();

        //create PYEMPELEMENT as much as employee element count   
        //if(){----validation if checkbox AllEmployee not ticked
        for(PYEMPPAYPERIOD__c pp : empPayPeriod) {
            e = new PYEMPELEMENT__c();
            e.Budget_Item_Code__c = pp.Period__r.Element_Name__r.Budget_Item_Code__c;
            e.Company_Name__c = pp.Employee_No__r.Company_Name__r.Id;
            e.Element_Group__c = pp.Period__r.Element_Name__r.Element_Group__c;
            e.Element_Name__c = pp.Period__r.Element_Name__r.Id;
            e.Element_Type__c = pp.Period__r.Element_Name__r.Element_Type__c;
            e.Element_Value__c = pp.Period__r.Element_Name__r.Content_Value__c;
            e.Employee_No__c = pp.Employee_No__r.Id;
            e.End_Date__c = pp.Period__r.Element_Name__r.End_Date__c;
            e.Group_Display__c = pp.Period__r.Element_Name__r.Group_Display__c;
            e.Group_Order__c = pp.Period__r.Element_Name__r.Group_Order__c;
            e.Is_Value__c = pp.Period__r.Element_Name__r.Is_Value__c;
            e.Period__c = pp.Period__r.Period__r.Id;
            e.Process_Sequence_ID__c = pp.Period__r.Element_Name__r.Process_Sequence_ID__c;
            e.Start_Date__c = pp.Period__r.Element_Name__r.Start_Date__c;
            e.Process_Flag__c = 2;

                empElement.add(e);

        }   
        insert empElement;
        ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.INFO, 'Record has been successfully proceed'));   
     }

}
```

Comment: Can you share your controller code as well?

Comment: my controller already shared, hehe, any idea why it's not working?  Thank you @developer__c

Comment: What code have you tried, and what error message you you getting?

Comment: in my vf page, i add rendered="{!ProcessAll}"
then error message : 
Unknown property 'preProcessController.ProcessAll' @developer__c

Answer (score 0):

You could change `<apex:panelGroup id="listEmployee">` to have a rendered tag on it, that is set to the opposite value of the tickbox {!ProcessAll}. So if the tickbox is ticked the employee selection pane is hidden.

```
         <apex:pageblocksectionItem >
            <apex:outputLabel value="Payroll Period" for="listPeriod"/>
            <apex:selectList id="listPeriod" size="1" multiselect="false" value="{!selectedPeriod}" style="width:150px"> 
                <apex:selectOptions value="{!Period}"/> 
                <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="listEmployee"/>
            </apex:selectList>   
        </apex:pageblocksectionItem>

        <apex:pageblocksectionItem >
            <apex:outputLabel value="All Employee" />
            <apex:inputCheckbox id="ProcessAll" label="Process All">
            </apex:inputCheckbox>
        </apex:pageblocksectionItem>

        <apex:panelGroup id="listEmployee" rendered="{!ProcessAll}">
            <c:MultiselectPicklist leftLabel="Available Employee" leftOptions="{!allEmployee}"
                                   rightLabel="Selected Employee" rightOptions="{!selectedEmployee}"
                                   size="14" width="475px"/>
        </apex:panelGroup>    

        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
            <apex:commandButton id="RunPreProcess" value="Run Pre Process" action="{!RunPreprocess}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

    </apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock>
```